# Trouble with Running a Continuous Task in the Background

Tags: worker, asp.net-core-6.0, background-service, ihostedservice

I want to add notifications at certain intervals using `BackgroundService`, but the waiting interval I set is 10 seconds in this example, the program running ends when it is finished.

Service like this:

```cs
public class BackGroundWorkerService : BackgroundService
     {
         private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

         public BackGroundWorkerService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
         {
             _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
         }

         protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
         {
             while (true)
             {
                 using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                 {
                     var notificationService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<INotificationService>();
                     var notificationMessage = NotificationMessageService.GetMessage(
                         NotificationMessageTypes.Added,
                         TableNamesConstants.Expenses,
                         "AA"
                     );

                     await notificationService.AddAsync(notificationMessage, "Notification Title | Try", userId: 1);

                     Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Here's the configuration in `Program`.cs:

```
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
             }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
             {
                 logging.ClearProviders();
             }).ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
             {
                 services.AddHostedService<BackGroundWorkerService>(); // Add background service
             });`
```

Additional info:

```
await notificationService.AddAsync(notificationMessage, "Notification Title | Try", userId: 1);
```

If I don't write the line, the problem disappears, but my goal is to add it anyway. I thought about whether it is related to the `unitOfWork` structure, etc. But I do not throw the global error page. it ends the work directly, I couldn't understand the reason.

I want to add notifications at certain intervals using `BackgroundService`.

Comment: Exceptions from background services do not result in a global error page; they are actually silently ignored. I recommend catching exceptions in your `ExecuteAsync` and logging them.

Comment: Stephen Cleary's advice works to determine what is wrong. The exception is, "System.InvalidOperationException: ''MyBlog.Data.Concrete.UnitOfWork' type only implements IAsyncDisposable. Use DisposeAsync to dispose the container.'" but idk how to handle this problem, still..

Comment: Call `CreateAsyncScope` instead of `CreateScope`, and use `await using`.